# Populating 2D Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, 2d

How would I input the same randomized values 27 times into that array $data?

It outputs a correctly formatted table with one row of randomized values, now just need to redo these values 27 times.

The array is two dimensional would that makes things harder?

Any and all help is appreciated very much I am just a beginner.

```
    <html>
<STYLE type="text/css">
    td{
        border-left: 1px solid #f09d09;
    }

    th{
        border: 1px solid #f09d09;
    }
</STYLE>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Student Number</th>
          <th>Coursework Mark</th>
          <th>Exam Mark</th>
          <th>Module Mark</th>
          <th>Module  Result</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
<?php

    $examPassmark = 40; //Hardcoded exam pass mark
    $courseworkPassmark = 40; // Hardcoded coursework passmark
    $n      =   rand(1,27); 
    $sn     =   "B00" . rand(200000,599999); //randomised student number with the prefix B00 e.g B00-299999
    $cwm    =   rand(25,100); //randomised coursework mark
    $em     =   rand(25,100); // randomised exam mark
    $mm     =   round(((($cwm / 200) * 20) +  (($em / 200) * 80) * 2)) ; //exam weighting is cw/e = 20/80 
    $mr     =   'Fail'; 
    $stack  =   array(""); 

    if($em > $examPassmark && $cwm > $courseworkPassmark) //This if statement states that ONLY if both Coursework and the exam are passed will a student pass the module
    {
        $mr = 'Pass';
    }else{
        $mr = 'Fail';
    }

    if($cwm < $courseworkPassmark) //Checks to see if the student passed coursework
    {
        $com = 'Resit CourseWork';  
    }
    else if($em < $examPassmark) // Checks to see if the student passed the exam
    {
        $com = 'Resit Exam';
    }else{
        $com = 'None';          //outputted if both are passed
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <= 27; $i++)
    {
        $data = array( array($n, $sn, $cwm, $em, $mm, $mr, $com) //Here we have an two dimensional array that will be filled with the values created above
                     );     
        $data[$i] .= $stack;
    }

        for ($row = 0; $row < 27; $row++) //rows (I use 8 to give each column padding so it isnt squeezed together)
        {           
            for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) //columns output to the number of entries in the array $data
            {
                    echo "<td>".$data[$row][$col]."</td>"; //within each column print out the value held within $data
            }
        }
    echo '</table>'; //end the table
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: As its a 2 dimensional array im not sure how to increment to the next value in the array. Then how to print through the values of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there..  with a few modifications to your code, you can get the data correctly into the array, and print it...  I'm going to add comments to the modified code, so you can see what I changed, and why.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 27; $i++)
{
    $data[] = array($n, $sn, $cwm, $em, $mm, $mr, $com, $stack);
    // There is no need to use $i in the array assignment here, the array inserts already start at zero
    // On top of that, there is no need to have a 3 dimensional array, if you're trying to
    // Get the values to correctly print into a table.
    // Lastly, you can simply add $stack to the array, rather than having to add it on with another line.
}

for ($row = 0; $row < 27; $row++)
{
    echo "<tr>"; // This needs to exist, of course, in order to separate the rows
    for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) //columns output to the number of entries in the array $data
    {
        echo "<td>".$data[$row][$col]."</td>";
        // Otherwise, your code here is fine.
    }
    echo "</tr>"; // see above
}
```

Comment: I can only hope I didn't misinterpret your goal.

Comment: Awesome the worked perfectly. I just need to now randomize each entry but thats me over the hard part thanks alot!

Comment: Welcome; glad I could assist.

Comment: Also, as to randomizing the data for each row, you could just shove your assignment in the `$data` loop.

Comment: thats exactly what I did. Looks a bit loopy and long, but its functional and can be cleaned up. Thanks again!